# Create MySQL database name using variable from date

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution

for the variable

```
dbnya="echo $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
```

When running below code, I will get an error (SQL syntax error)

```
mysql -u root -pthepass -e "CREATE DATABASE demo$dbnya CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin"
```

The second command will work if I'm using `dbnya=20120423230524` as first command

Comment: Since your variables holds the string `echo 2012042323524`, the SQL command is `CREATE DATABASE demoecho 2012042323524 CHAR...` -- note the extraneous string **"echo "**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks instead of quotes.

```
dbnya=`echo $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`
```

The backtick (`) indicates the text is to be executed as a command, thus setting the variable to the output of the command.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use the echo command:

```
$> dbnya="echo $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
$> echo $dbnya
echo 20120423170042
```

Just remove it from the command, dbnya will receive the result of the date evaluation:

```
$> dbnya="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
$> echo $dbnya
20120423170114
```

Comment: I think you can remove the quotes too, in this case at least.

Comment: Yes @Mat, `dbnya=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)` is enough :)